# new Date return NaN or a wrong time starting from server date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, nan

I'm trying to get server time at start and update it, cause i've to cotnrol some elements with real time. The problem is that if my `serverTime` doesn't have T the time is NaN on firefox and IE, but if i replace the empty space with T on chrome and IE i've a wrong time.

I now the work-around of replacing white space with T sucks but im outta of time :)

Thanks everybody

At start:

```
$tmpTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Head:

```
<script>
var serverTime = '<?=$tmpTime?>';
serverTime = serverTime.replace(" ", "T");
</script>
```

Script:

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log(serverTime);
    var tmpTime = new Date(serverTime);
    console.log(tmpTime);
    var t = tmpTime.getTime();
    t = t + 1000;
    tmpTime = new Date(t);
    serverTime = t;
    if (tmpTime.getMinutes() < 10) {
        var minutes = "0" + tmpTime.getMinutes();
    } else {
        var minutes = tmpTime.getMinutes();
    };
    newTime = tmpTime.getHours() + ":" + minutes;
    $('#liveTime').text(newTime);
    if ($("#program li[time-id='" + newTime + "'][class='alert']").length !== 0) {
        alert("Lo streaming da te programmato sta per iniziare!");
        $("#program li[time-id='" + newTime + "'][class='alert']").removeClass("alert");
    }
    titleToShow();

}, 1000);


function titleToShow() {
    $("#program li").each(function () {
        var prevTime = $(this).prev("li").attr("time-id");

        var thisTime = $(this).attr("time-id");
        var nextTime = $(this).next("li").attr("time-id");
        currentTime = Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' + newTime);
        prevTime = Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' + prevTime);
        nextTime = Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' + nextTime);
        thisTimeNew = Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' + thisTime);

        if (currentTime >= thisTimeNew && currentTime < nextTime && currentTime > prevTime) {
            title = $(this).find("p").text();
            if (title != $("p#playingTitle").text()) {
                $("p#playingTitle").text(title);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Until ES5, the parsing of strings by the Date constructor was entirely implementation dependent. ES5 defines a [version of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), but it is not supported by all browsers in use and the string in the OP without the "T" is not compliant. The most cross-browser and backward compatible method is described in CBroe's answer, which should work in any moderately compliant ECMAScript implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use a *formated* date, just pass the Unix timestamp value to the script (don’t forget to multiply it by 1000, because JS works with milliseconds).

```
var serverTime = <?php echo time(); ?>;
var tmpTime = new Date(serverTime * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it now wotk on chrome and Firefox but IE still have problem.